# How to ignore first line of content in curl standard output?

Tags: linux, curl

When I use `curl -s` to access a text file, it will display the entire content. Is there any way to ignore the first line of content?

Test text file link:

```
curl -s https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Automattic/_s/master/languages/readme.txt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pipe and use another command to remove the first line, for example using `tail`

```
curl -s https://... | tail +2
```

or `sed`

```
curl -s https://... | sed '1d'
```

Comment: thank for your reply! If access multiple files at the same time, can delete the first line of each file?  `curl -s https://... https://...`

Comment: Likely the easiest way is to run `curl` once per url, eg. `curl -s https://...| tail +2; curl -s https://... | tail +2; ...`